# data stream between Kerberized kafka cluster to hadoop cluster using Spring boot

Tags: hadoop, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kerberos

I have a streaming use case to develop an Spring boot application where it should read data from kafka topic and put into hdfs path, I got two distinct cluster for kafka and hadoop. 
Application worked fine without having kerberos authentication in kafka cluster and hadoop being kerberized.

Issues started when both cluster being kerberized, At the same time i could only authenticate into only one cluster.

I did few analysis/googling , i could not find much of help, 
My theory is we could not login/authenticate into two kerberized cluster at same jvm instance because we need to set REALM and KDC details in code which are not client specific but jvm specific,

It might happen that i did not used proper APIs, I am very new to Spring boot.

I know we can do this by setting **cross realm trust** between clusters but i am looking for application level solutions if possible.

**I got few questions**

1. is it possible to login/authenticate two separate kerberized cluster at same jvm instance, if possible? please help me, use of Spring boot is preferred.
2. What would be the best solution to stream data from kafka cluster to hadoop cluster.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the best solution to stream data from kafka cluster to hadoop cluster.

Kafka's Connect API is for streaming integration of sources and targets with Kafka, using just configuration files - no coding! The [HDFS connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html#quickstart) is what you want, and supports Kerberos authentication. It is open source and available [standalone](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/) or as part of [Confluent Platform](https://www.confluent.io/download/).

Comment: Thanks Robin,, HDFS connector and confluent platform looks great, will definitely like to explore more. Lets see if anyone solve this kind of problem with Spring boot